# how to create a curve between two div using css?

Tags: css

I want to create a curve from one div to another like this:
[image]

from the top div to the bottoms
how to create the line in css?

Do I have to write it in canvas?

Comment: I suggest to use a library like https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/ .. doing this on your own would be overkill imo

Comment: @PRSHL thank you . Do I need write canvas or just css can do it? I want just a curve  Is it need to use the library?

Comment: Canvas should work ...

Comment: @Nechoj I want to use div and canvas to write the curve I will try it

Comment: Maybe you need `position: absolute` for the `canvas`  to make it appear 'behind' the `div`s

Comment: @Nechoj but if there is overflow:auto and user can scroll the divs the postion is changed

Comment: No problem if you have an enclosing `div` with `position: relative` and inside the canvas with `position: abolute` which is then interpreted as absolute position within the enclosing `div`. This is not `fixed`!

Comment: @Nechoj not not the `position` but there may are many divs in a line and will overflow and user can scroll it to view the one that is not displayed

Comment: In any case you need to fix the position of the divs and the canvas inside an enclosing div, otherwise the lines will not end up ate the divs.